# Trying to update Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Error Code (1)

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to upgrade Ubuntu to a newer version but when I run:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

The error message is:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 292477 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gdb_7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking gdb (7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.3) over (7.7-0ubuntu3.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gdb_7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.3_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/gdb.1.gz', which is also in package gdb-arm-none-eabi 7.6.50.20131218-0ubuntu1+1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/gdb_7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a package called: "GNU-Debugger". After removing it everything worked fine.